# How to choose a stock?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, trading-systems, diversification

So far, I have only been working on systems that track numerous stocks and evaluate which present the best opportunities at a given time.

I have grown curious about building a day-trading system that tracks only one stock but looks for various patterns on the 1 minute timeframe.
These patterns would be found through intensive research on that single stock. This system would 'know' this stock really well, and would obviously be at a risk of being over-fitted, or left unprofitable when the sentiment on the stock changes.

How do you narrow down the search for such a stock, limiting the disadvantages of such an undiversified approach?

Comment: Well is there a reason you'd only want to trade one stock? You can only really get the benefits of diversifcation by actually diversifying or hedging.

Comment: Well, this isn't about getting the benefits of diversification without diversifying,  it's about the best way to approach an exploratory but risky methodology...

Comment: How about SPY as the one "stock", arguably the most liquid and important stock of all. If you can predict this one you've got it made.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. This was more of a thought experiment than a serious strategy idea, but I understand the down votes and why this wasn't popular, so my apologies to anyone whose time I wasted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a terrible idea. If you can have such an automated system for one stock, you can have it for many stocks. Then, since you're a serious investor, you want to take into account the commonalities and relations between stocks. At the very least, this will allow you to do perform hedging and exploit commonalities between similar stocks. In this case, you might go for a more traditional quantitative finance approach just as well.

So to answer the question in your title: I don't think anybody can give you practical advice on this.